# Implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I find the derivative of $xe^y - x^{-3}y = 12$?

Normally I would solve for $y$ but I have no idea how to do that with this one. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You meant implicit differentiation.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use Chain rule. Given a function $g(y(x))$, 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(g(y)) = \frac{dg(y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}. $$
For instance, differentiating the first term with respect to $x$ using Product Rule yields
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^y\right) = x\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^y\right) + e^y = x\frac{d}{dy}\left(e^y\right)\frac{dy}{dx} + e^y = xe^y\frac{dy}{dx} + e^y. $$